# Как с помощью .htaccess сделать такое перенаправление?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Через .htaccess пытаюсь сделать, чтобы у url такого типа:

```
https://toster.ru/?_escaped_fragment_=/about/
```

Превращались в такой:

```
https://toster.ru/snapshot/about/
```

Мудрил-мудрил, и получил такой конфиг:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1? [NC,L]
```

Но он не работает

Answer (score 1):

Надо было добавить `[NC,R=301,L]` в последнюю строку

Answer (score 0):

Условие можно записать немного компактнее, поместив одно из условий в `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /snapshots/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Кстати, `[NC]` в условии лишний, поскольку ничего текстового здесь не сравнивается.